# sumo simulator is showing "SUMO_HOME variable not set" and "unable to connect"

Tags: command-line, environment-variables

```
my@my-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$ cd iitk/
my@my-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~/iitk$ netconvert --osm-files iitk.osm -o iitk.net.xml
Warning: Environment variable SUMO_HOME is not set, using built in type maps.
Warning: Environment variable SUMO_HOME is not set, schema resolution will use slow website lookups.
Error: unable to connect socket for URL 'http://sumo.dlr.de/xsd/types_file.xsd'
 In file 'built in type map'
 At line/column 1/0.

  The types could not be loaded from 'built in type map'.
Quitting (on error).
```

Answer (score 0):

The first one is a warning only. If you want to get rid of it, do something like

`export SUMO_HOME=/home/sumo-0.30.0/sumo/`

Comment: even after running the command I am getting this error                                       "  my@my-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~/iitk$ export SUMO_HOME=/home/sumo-0.25.0/sumo/bin/
my@my-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~/iitk$ netconvert --osm-files iitk.osm -o iitk.net.xml
Error: Could not open types-file '/home/sumo-0.25.0/sumo/bin//data/typemap/osmNetconvert.typ.xml'.
Quitting (on error). "

Comment: Is the version correct?

Comment: try  `export SUMO_HOME=/home/sumo-0.30.0/sumo/`

Comment: my sumo version is 0.27.1  "my@my-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~/iitk$ export SUMO_HOME=/home/sumo-0.27.1/sumo/ my@my-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~/iitk$ netconvert --osm-files iitk.osm -o iitk.net.xml
Error: Could not open types-file '/home/sumo-0.27.1/sumo//data/typemap/osmNetconvert.typ.xml'.
Quitting (on error)."

Comment: it is still showing the above error "Error: Could not open types-file '/home/sumo-0.27.0/sumo//data/typemap/osmNetconvert.typ.xml'.
Quitting (on error).
"